# Xpath: Select parent link matching three child attributes

Tags: xpath

I need to select a link using xpath that matches the following three criterion:

parent @class = 'testItem'

child @class = 'icon icon_checked'

text = 'test text goes here!'

i'm unsure about where to put the text attribute in the xpath reference. i've tried many permutations of the following:

```
//a[@class="testItem" and child::span[@class="icon icon_checked"] and li[text()="test text goes here!"]]
```

my issue is that the text part is not in its own span.

here's the raw example:

```
<li>
<a class="testItem2" data-code="2" href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="icon icon_checked"></span>
test text goes here2!
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="testItem" data-code="2" href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="icon icon_checked"></span>
test text goes here!
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Multiple solutions, some problems you might be having may stem from the text actually starting with a newline & ending with it. You might want to use `contains()` or `normalize-space()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I've found the answer.

I can simply change the last part of my xpath from li[text()="test text goes here!"] to .[text()="test text goes here!"]].

My final working xpath is:

```
//a[@class='testItem' and child::span[@class='icon icon_checked'] and .[text()='test text goes here!']]
```